# How to create a new htaccess file for subdomain, outside the www directory?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

i created a new folder like /var/websites/menora.sichermove.co.in, and staged all files to the directory , now i am getting 'Internal Server Error' please help me to create a new htaccess file for sub domain?

Answer (score 0):

Simply open a new file in Notepade++ and copy the following code in it and, upload in the director where u want by using file zilla..  and let me know when you done it..
thanks

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        #Removes access to the system folder by users.
        #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
        #previously this would not have been possible.
        #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

        #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
        #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
        #Submitted by: Fabdrol
        #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

        #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
        #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
        #request to index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>


    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin|dotproject|images|fonts|js|css|.htpasswd|robots\.txt)
```